# Tool to work with embedded Excel spreadsheets in .NET Core

Tags: web-apps, .net, microsoft-excel

I am working on a project which receives an .xls from a service which then needs to be displayed in a web app. This web app needs to be written in .NET Core, so not necessarily any Excel manipulation tool will work, if they don't work with .NET Core.

I have found potential tools by Telerik and Syncfusion, but unfortunately I'm having issues with Visual Studio right now, so I haven't been able to try them out, but once I have, I'll update this question if needed.